# React doesn't render API data

Tags: reactjs

Im building a recipe App and I got stuck and there is no error display or anything that can help me, Its my first time working with APIS in React and Im a little bit lost thats why im asking.

I´m trying to fetch data from [this API](https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php) and  I don´t know why the properties will not show on the screen since I ve another example where it does.

I can see in the console with the React Developer extension that the properties are passed to the state so that´s fine and I dont understand why I cannot access or why it doesnt render.

In the other example doesn't get the data from an API it gets the data from a local object in json. Does it work different when it comes an API? Any idea?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipes: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({ recipes: json });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log("parsed error", error));
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="box">{this.state.recipes.strMeal}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks okay, but you need to render somehow your backend data:

```
fetchData() {
  fetch("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({ recipes: json.meals });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("parsed error", error));
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box">
        {this.state.recipes.map(m => <p>{m.strMeal}</p>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

`recipes` is a json with `meals` key that is an array. Each element in the array has `strMeal` key (name of the meal).

Comment: Hi Tomasz,  I Tried and  got this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined